# Paint and erase with the mouse on an image

Tags: java, graphics

I am learning java, and I would like to be able to paint in an image while dragging the mouse.
Search google but everything is very confusing.

In summary I need:

1-create a window

2-create an image

3-show image in window

4-draw with the right mouse-click on the image

5-delete with the left mouse-click on the image

Comment: It looks like you have a good start by breaking this down into smaller pieces. I suggest you figure out how to solve each of these pieces one at a time. For example, you can google "java create a window" to find some examples of how to do this.

Comment: 1) In Java, you can use Swing or JavaFX to create a graphical user interface (GUI).  Here are links to Oracle's tutorials on Swing and JavaFX.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: its usual to draw with left and erase with right mouse button... Also not with click but button down event instead.